# Can't access pure index data in option dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm doing calculating work from yahoo option web page with the following code:

```
from pandas.io.data import Options

aapl = Options('aapl', 'yahoo')
data = aapl.get_all_data()

middle = data.query('Expiry == "2015-08-28" & Type == "call"')
strike = middle.ix[:, 0]
```

I find I can't access `'Strike'` column with above code, when I retrieve data of column 0, I get `'Ask'` column. It seems pandas only looks `'Strike'` as index, instead of data column.

if I use following code:

```
strike = middle.index.levels[0]
```

the returned result is all the element of `'Strike'` index, but not the real column data of `'Strike`' from the query above `( middle = data.query('Expiry == "2015-08-28" & Type == "call"') ).`

If I print middle, I can see a `'Strike'` column data in the result, but if I print middle.columns, there is no `'Strike'` in the result. So It seems `'Strike'` is a pure index.

Who can tell me how to access the data of such a pure index?

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to "Explode" a nested index is to call `reset_index`:

```
data = data.reset_index()
data.head()
   Strike     Expiry  Type               Symbol   Last    Bid    Ask   Chg PctChg  Vol  Open_Int      IV  Root IsNonstandard Underlying  Underlying_Price          Quote_Time
0   34.29 2016-01-15  call  AAPL160115C00034290  80.85  81.65  82.05  1.35  1.70%    3       420  83.79%  AAPL         False       AAPL            115.96 2015-08-17 16:00:00
1   34.29 2016-01-15   put  AAPL160115P00034290   0.03   0.00   0.04  0.00  0.00%    2     12469  67.19%  AAPL         False       AAPL            115.96 2015-08-17 16:00:00
2   35.71 2016-01-15  call  AAPL160115C00035710  77.30  80.25  80.60  0.00  0.00%   39       113  80.66%  AAPL         False       AAPL            115.96 2015-08-17 16:00:00
3   35.71 2016-01-15   put  AAPL160115P00035710   0.05   0.00   0.04  0.00  0.00%  150      9512  64.84%  AAPL         False       AAPL            115.96 2015-08-17 16:00:00
4   37.14 2016-01-15  call  AAPL160115C00037140  78.55  78.80  79.20  0.00  0.00%   10         0  78.52%  AAPL         False       AAPL            115.96 2015-08-17 16:00:00
```

Then you can just access your column as `data.Strike` or `data['Strike']`:

```
data.Strike.head()
Out[175]: 
0    34.29
1    34.29
2    35.71
3    35.71
4    37.14
Name: Strike, dtype: float64
```